# Raycasting in unity jumping to a wrong position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am having a problem with Raycasting. All I want to do is always know the position of my cursor in world space and it works, but only if the cursor is moving. when the cursor is not moving it jumps to a random point around 4 units down on the x and z-axis.

```cs
public class CameraMovementRay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCam;
    Ray cursorRay;
    Vector3 playerPos;
    public RaycastHit cursorHit;
    public LayerMask clickPlain;
    public bool cursorHittingFloor;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cursorRay = playerCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(cursorRay, out cursorHit, 100f, clickPlain))
        {
            print(cursorHit.point);
            Debug.DrawLine(cursorRay.origin, cursorHit.point, Color.red);
            cursorHittingFloor = true;

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Not on the grund");
            cursorHittingFloor = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the script works properly but if you hold the mouse stationary the raycast shoots downward?

Comment: not downwards but off in another direction for example: if the ray, while the cursor was moving, went from the camera to a point (4, 0, 2) when the cursor is stationary the ray would then move to a point at like (-1, 0, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wasn't working out but I did find code that does

``
public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Camera playerCamera;

Plane movementPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, 0f);
Vector3 lookPoint;

Ray CursorRay;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    CursorRay = playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    float enter = 0.0f;

    movementPlane.Raycast(CursorRay, out enter);
    lookPoint = CursorRay.GetPoint(enter);
    print(lookPoint);
    Debug.DrawLine(CursorRay.origin, lookPoint);

    transform.LookAt(lookPoint);

}
```

}
``

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint instead of Camera.ScreenPointToRay?  I think it might work better for your purpose because it takes a Vector2 (MousePosition) in pixels and converts it conveniently to World Space Point. The Unity documentation to what I'm referring to is: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Let me know how it works out